# How to require one of two possible options in a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I'm trying to configure a couple options in a Ruby script using `OptionParser`. I'd like them both to be optional but require that at least one is used. One option would allow for a single value to be passed from the command line. The other option will tell the script to use a file containing multiple values to be iterated over.

This is all I've been able to come up with:

```
options = {}

parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.banner = "Usage: sat_server_delete.rb [options]"
  opts.on('-f', '--file file', 'File') do |file|
    options[:file] = file;
  end

  opts.on('-s', '--server server', 'Server') do |server|
    options[:server] = server
  end
end.parse!
```

I haven't worked out the logic each will use yet. Right now I'd be happy to just see an error indicating that neither have been provided. So far I'm not getting even that. The script simply runs to completion and returns to a prompt.

I looked at the [Ruby Doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) for `OptionParser`, but It isn't clear to me how to accomplish what I'm trying. Is it even possible to have an either/or situation with options? I'm not even sure if what I already have makes sense. I'm basically just attempting to copy the logic without fully understanding what it is doing.

Comment: I guess your are asking `OptionParser` to do more than its fair share. Its share is to *parse options*. What you do with the result (the `options` hash) is entirely up to you. After parsing all the command line you can decide to `exit` if neither option is present. Of course you *should* indicate this behavior in your `usage`.

Comment: @Patru that sounds right to me. Make it an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `options` hash after the `parse!` as in

```
if options[:file] && options[:server]
  puts "may have only one of -f and -s"
  exit
elsif !options[:file] && !options[:server]
  puts "must have at least one of -f and -s"
  exit
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if `OptionParser` had this functionality built in.